# spec_tbl_df is over 10 times slower on same opperations as a normal tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, readr

So I was really ripping my hair out why two different sessions of R with the same data were producing wildly different times to complete the same task.
After a lot of restarting R, cleaning out all my variables, and really running a clean R, I found the issue: the new data structure provided by `vroom` and `readr` is, for some reason, super sluggish on my script. Of course the easiest thing to solve this is to convert your data into a tibble as soon as you load it in. Or is there some other explanation, like poor coding praxis in my functions that can explain the sluggish behavior? Or, is this a bug with recent updates of these packages? If so and if someone is more experienced with reporting bugs to tidyverse, then here is a `repex` showing the behavior cause I feel that this is out of my ballpark.

```r
#Load packages
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)
library(vroom)
library(tidyr)
library(microbenchmark)
#Genenrate some dummy data
ex_data <- tibble(
  sd = 1,
  mean = 1:1000,
  a1 = rnorm(1000, mean, sd),
  a2 = rnorm(1000, mean, sd),
  a3 = rnorm(1000, mean, sd)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    a1 = if_else(a1<mean, NA_real_, a1),
    a2 = if_else(a2<mean, NA_real_, a2),
    a3 = if_else(a3<mean, NA_real_, a3)
  )
#Wrapper function discovering the behavioure
impute_row <- function(mean, sd, data){
  if(!anyNA(data)){
    return(data)
  }else{
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
    data[is.na(data)] <-  rnorm(n = sum(is.na(data)), mean = mean, sd = sd)
    return(data)
  }
}
#Main function
imputer <- function(data){
  data %>% 
    mutate(
      data = pmap(list(mean, sd, data), impute_row)
    ) %>% 
    unnest(cols = data)
}
#Generate dummy file
out_file <- tempfile(fileext = "csv")
vroom_write(ex_data, out_file, ",")
#Read it in
ex_data_spc <- vroom(out_file, col_types = cols()) %>% 
  nest(data = -c(mean, sd))
#Nest the original data as well
ex_data <- ex_data %>% 
  nest(data = -c(mean, sd))
#Benchmark
microbenchmark(
  tib = imputer(ex_data),
  spc_tib = imputer(ex_data_spc),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#>      tib   82.81192   87.45288   89.19118   90.47263   91.2216   93.4418    10
#>  spc_tib 1041.90378 1070.00579 1244.97090 1076.92022 1093.0054 2780.0722    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Which at the worst-case scenario is almost 30 times slower then running on a tibble.

Comment: I remember seeing something like this. have you searched the issues on the github repos of the relevant packages?

Comment: Oh, ok. No, I could not really navigate my way to find where the issues on GitHub were located, just started with GitHub a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/r-lib/vroom/issues/29) is the issue I had in mind. These problems have been known to happen with vroom, rather than with the `spec_tbl_df` class, which does not really do much.

`vroom` does all sorts of things to try and speed reading up; AFAIK mostly by lazy reading. That's how you get all those different components when comparing the two datasets.

With vroom:

```r
~~~(snip)~~~
ex_data_spc <- vroom(out_file, col_types = cols()) %>% 
  nest(data = -c(mean, sd))
~~~(snip)~~~

#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#>  spc_tib 1679.2088 1704.3085 2106.864 1731.6694 1942.9444 4918.4498    10   b
#>      tib  149.8716  158.8548  169.489  170.3735  182.5681  192.8533    10  a

all.equal(ex_data, ex_data_spc)
#>    [1] "Component \"data\": Component 1: Attributes: < Names: 1 string mismatch >"                                                 
#>    [2] "Component \"data\": Component 1: Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 2 components >"                        
#>    [3] "Component \"data\": Component 1: Attributes: < Component \"class\": Lengths (3, 4) differ (string compare on first 3) >"   
#>    [4] "Component \"data\": Component 1: Attributes: < Component \"class\": 3 string mismatches >"                                 
#>    [5] "Component \"data\": Component 1: Attributes: < Component 2: Modes: numeric, externalptr >"  
                               
~~~(snip)~~~
```

With readr:

```
~~~(snip)~~~
ex_data_spc <- readr::read_csv(out_file, col_types = cols()) %>% 
  nest(data = -c(mean, sd))
~~~(snip)~~~
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>  spc_tib 148.9432 161.7315 181.2137 184.4592 191.9048 219.7883    10   a
#>      tib 161.9441 166.7826 175.3644 175.3354 181.4598 197.5544    10   a

all.equal(ex_data, ex_data_spc)
#> [1] TRUE
```

You could post your reprex to that issue if you're feeling like it.

Comment: Oh, I see, I did know that vroom did lazy loading, but I guess I was too frustrated to figure out that it was because of that and not the class itself. Do you think it will help the vroom developer if I post it there?

Comment: yes, I think so. Try to compress the reprex though; there's probably no need to do so many operations to observe the phenomenon. Also, you can just use `iris` as toy dataset.